# Conditional probability and connectiveness in a graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics

I have a set of nodes A and a connected unidrected graph G consisting of elements in A. I can think of $P(a|b)$ as the probability going from an node b to a, which is equal to the number of edges connecting a and b divided by the total number of edges coming out of b. Then we can calculate $p(c|b) = \sum p(a|b) p(c|a) $ over all possible a connected with both $b$ and $c$. This is just the chain rule in basic probability.

Suppose that I have a simple graph $a - b - c$. Using this logic one get that $p(c|a) = p(b|a) p(c | b) = 1 * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ but that contradicts the fact that by the definition of how the conditional probability is defined in this case. What is going wrong here?

I mean intuitively this is trying to capture the fact that $a$ is connected with $c$ indirectly, but I do not get how this is rigorously justified.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $P(c\mid b)=\sum_a P(c\mid a)P(a\mid b)$ is incorrect, as your example proves.

$\sum_a P(c\mid a)P(a\mid b)$ is the probability of moving from $b$ to some node $a$, and then moving from $a$ to $c$. In other words, it is the probability of moving from $b$ to $c$ *in two steps*. On the other hand, $P(c\mid b)$ was just the probability of moving from $c$ to $b$ *in one step*. The two sides of your equation are the probabilities of different events, hence have no reason to be equal.